# Best Practices to store IIS config in TFS/Version Control

Tags: asp.net, iis, tfs, msbuild

We have a cluster of identical IIS machines. I'd like to keep IIS Configuration settings in TFS, and integrate into the deployment process.

This would allow us to edit in one place, ease server scaling, rollback bad changes etc.

I'm thinking of using a web.config transform but apply to to the applicationHost.config to allow deploying to dev, uat production environments.

So my question is

- Has anyone versioned the configuration files in %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config
- Is there better way to keep these server settings in version control?

Comment: An alternate is to automate configuring the site/server using appcmd.exe and then store the script. You'll need some script to apply the changes anyway.

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi, Thats a good idea, the problem though is we need custom tweaks to the applicationHost.config file. I'll look into this though, it might get us 90% of the way there.

Comment: Using appcmd.exe you can modify applicationHost.config

Answer (score 3):

If there aren't any manual tweaks to the config, an alternative would be to put the configuration in a Powershell Desired State Configuration (DSC).

This would allow you to scale more parts of the configuration (windows features etc) and deploy them for you. With the latest version of release management (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/05/22/release-management-for-microsoft-visual-studio-2013-with-update-3-ctp1-is-live.aspx), you can integrate this in your build and deployment pipeline.

Comment: Or, really, you can just use RM to manage the values that go into config files at deployment time by leveraging tokenized config files.

Comment: For the config of the applications yes. For changes to the applicationHost.config i.m.h.o not. By placing them in the dsc profile, there not directly bounded to RM and other tooling is still an option.